# C# - Dealing with database type may be decimal or double

Tags: c#

I'm importing data from a database into a table with the following code:

```
public double[,] toValueArray(string fieldPrefix, int firstIndex, int lastIndex)
        {
            // return a bunch of value columns as a double array
            double[,] outArr = new double[TableRowCount,lastIndex-firstIndex+1];

            for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++)
            {
                var col = TheDataTable.Columns[fieldPrefix + i];
                int r = -1;
                foreach (DataRow row in TheDataTable.Rows)
                {                    
                    outArr[++r, i - firstIndex] = (row[col] == null || row[col] == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : (double)row[col];                              
                }
            }

            return outArr; 
        }
```

The problem is, sometimes the database may be storing these as a decimal, and sometimes a double.  How can I convert use `.toDouble()` only if the type is a decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `0D` to have a double value and avoit implicit conversion of `int` to `double`. The conversion you can try doing it using the `ToDouble` static method from `Convert` type. For sample:

```
double setValue = 0D;
if (row[col] != null && row[col] != DBNull.Value)))
   setValue = (row[col] is decimal) ? Convert.ToDouble(row[col]) : (double) row[col];

outArr[++r, i - firstIndex] = setValue;
```